# how to change the width of combined custom view in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I wanted to implement a custom view which is combined by a ImageView and a TextView like this.

A class called IconTextView is created by extending TextView, and the onDraw function was rewrittend by this.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        //something are done before
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, target, getPaint());
        canvas.translate(target.right + 2, 0);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Then a IconTextView was added into the main layout like this.

```
<com.liujilong.carson.icontextview.IconTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    mobile:iconSrc="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="myIconTextView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />
```

The IconTextView shown in my phone like this.

Sorry that i can not post picture.

The problem is that the width of the View was still the width of the TextView, and I translated the canvas. So the text could not show totally.

How can I change the width of the IconTextView?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have to do anything as drastic as override `onDraw`.

You could just have a horizontal `LinearLayout` that has an `ImageView` and a `TextView`

Even simpler, you can set the left drawable of the `TextView` using the the attribute `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon"`.  If you have to change it in code, the corresponding method is `TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)`.  The images would have to be set up as drawable resources for this to work.

Is there something special about your custom view that these ideas won't work?